# MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation. How to handle this error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYkUo.png)

How can i solve this. Just showing  MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation

```
    at getTopology ..... at collection.insertOne .... at maybePromise..
```

```
const express = require('express');
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const password = 'NLJXkuGFhUd68@9';



const uri = "mongodb+srv://organicUser:NLJXkuGFhUd68@9@cluster0.px7rc.mongodb.net/organicdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, I am Working");
})



client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("organicdb").collection("products");

  // perform actions on the collection object
  const product = {name: "Modhu", price: 120, quantity: 30};
  collection.insertOne(product)
  .then(result => {
      console.log("One product added");
  })
  console.log("database connected");

});


app.listen(8000)
```

Comment: Look at example of connecting: [Quick Start](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/quick-start/)

Answer (score 29):

Just comment the code or remove client.close()

```
 finally {
           // await client.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm struggling with this, the author is referring to the idea that if your password contains certain characters, you must change them out for percent based codes: If the username or password includes the following characters:

: / ? # [ ] @

those characters must be converted using percent encoding.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace `@` with `%40` in the database password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have changed the method to be await and async, and I added await to the operation.
So the operation will be finished then the connection will be close

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to await before an async method when working with mongoose.

```js
await doc.save();
```